# Is it possible to run subset of Ansible Molecule scenarios based on some criteria

Tags: ansible, molecule

If I have a molecule directory with multiple scenarios is it possible to run a subset of the scenarios based on some criteria that I specify at run time

For example if I have the following 5 scenarios which are somehow categorised:

molecule

- scenario-1 (categories log-running)
- scenario-2 (categories os-a)
- scenario-3 (categories push, os-a)
- scenario-4 (categories weekend)
- scenario-5 (categories push)

molecule test --category push

=> run scenario-3 + scenario-5

molecule test --category os-a

=> run scenario-2 + scenario-3

molecule test --category long-running:weekend

=> run scenario-1 + scenario-4

I'm looking for something similar to Ansible tags but on the Molecule scenario level.

Comment: There's no such feature in molecule.

Answer (score 0):

Molecule does not have this level of scenario management. You can run molecule few times with different parameters based on your criteria (bash glue, I suppose, as usual).

Also, normally, when you have multiple scenarios, you want to run them in parallel (e.g. with power of your CI). Put it into `matrix` (or whatever this is called, `strategy`, etc), and add per-scenario condition; should it run it or not under given set of variables/circumstances.